# What is the meaning of "for many years to come" in this sentence?

Tags: clauses, adverbial-phrases

> The Bilingual Education Act is clearly a work-in-progress, and related
>   issues are likely to be found in the media and on the ballots for many
>   years to come.

There's one main clause, in skeleton form.

- Act is a work-in-progress, and related issues.

And

- are likely to be found in the media and on the ballots for many years to come

is used to describe ***related issues***.

I don't understand what's the usage of **for many years to come**?

Answer (score 7):

The phrase would be better structured like this:

> The Bilingual Education Act is clearly a work in progress; related issues are likely to be found, in the media and on the ballots, for many years to come.

The usage of "*for many years to come*" applies to "*related issues are likely to be found*". You could also say it like this:

> Related issues are likely to be found for many years into the future.